# What's the concise way to disable the page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In an imaginary situation, a user that shouldn't have access to a web page navigates to that page.
This page is a child page. The user should not have ANY functionality in this page, or even be able to see anything, but he (or she) should be able to still use the master page controls. What do you do to disable the page?

I thought perhaps making a control element .visible=false, but is this secure? Is there some other way I should be disabling a page?

Comment: Check their permissions and redirect them to another page?  Or you can disallow them completely with locations/roles.

Comment: I could definitely troll my way through it and make sure they can't do anything I don't want them to, but I figured ASP.NET (which I'm still relatively new to) would have some kind of preferred, pre-programmed easy way to shut the user out

Comment: What permissions structure are you using?  For instance, are you using the built-in membership provider backed by the standard SQL database structure?  There is an integrated way to control role/user-based access to specific pages or entire folders from web.config, which is what I meant by "locations/roles".

Comment: Basically I am performing a check inside of the page called by my custom library to find out their role. So I basically get either true or false when I call the function, true meaning they can see it, false meaning they can't. I'm just not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Redirect the user to a separate page with no data in it but have the default Master page to it. If you take him to a normal page but turn of the visibility of the controls , the user has a chance to look up in the browser and change the display property of the elements .. So the first option will be a lot secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a `nopermission.aspx` page that has the desired master page you wish, then in `Page_Load` redirect to that page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!HasPermission("User123"))   //User does not have permission
       Response.Redirect("nopermission.aspx");

    //otherwise, the page continues as required
}
```

You can put whatever friendly information you wish in the `nopermission` page

Comment: Better will be to use `Page_init` Event for this check. Or that will be much better if you're using any `BasePageClass` for your application. If yes then check this condition in `BasePage`'s `Overrided` `OnInit` method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your question, and assuming you're referring to ASP.Net Web Forms, then look into `<asp:LoginView />` controls.

It has an `<AnonymousTemlate />` and a `<LoggedInTemplate />` that represents the type of user respectively (anonymous or logged in, will be presented with the appropriate content).

It works with ASP.net Forms Authentication.

For detail: [MSDN - ASP.Net Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Hth....

Answer (score 0):

Making a control visible = false if a user doesn't have access to it should be secure because the nothing for this control is rendered by the server.

However, if a user tries to access a page they don't have access to, I usually log the activity and redirect them to a "sorry you don't have permissions to view this page" screen